# Why on getting queue can't convert String To Message

Tags: queue, activemq-classic

I'm getting strange runtime error on first row of handling queue with xml

```
private static async Task HandleMessage<TMessage, TConsumer>(Message message, IConsumer consumer, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken token) where TConsumer : class, ITypedConsumer<TMessage> {
    var msg = (TMessage)Convert.ChangeType(message.GetBody<string>(), typeof(TMessage));
    using var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
    var typedConsumer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<TConsumer>();
    await typedConsumer.ConsumeAsync(msg, token);
    await consumer.AcceptAsync(message);
}
```

Error says:

```
fail: ActiveMQ.Artemis.Client.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActiveMqConsumer[0]
System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'ActiveMQ.Artemis.Client.Message'.
at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType)
at ProjectName.Model.ActiveMqExtensions.HandleMessage[TMessage,TConsumer](Message message, IConsumer consumer, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken token) in D:\Projects\Adapters\Model\ActiveMqExtensions.cs:line 23
at ActiveMQ.Artemis.Client.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActiveMqConsumer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<<StartAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
```

I cheked XML string, and this code works fine:

```
string xml = message.GetBody<string>();
```

But this already rise error

```
string xml = message.GetBody<string>();
var msg = (TMessage)Convert.ChangeType(xml, typeof(TMessage));
```

Answer (score 0):

The solve was using typecast like this

```
var msg = (TMessage)Convert.ChangeType(message, typeof(TMessage));
```

because, author of this code seems did error, and it worked only for VS22 where project had precompiled binaries, so when i moved this code to VS19, all errors raised as is

Comment: If this is the correct answer you should mark it as such to help other who encounter this same issue in the future.